# Are steam-tradingcard counts limited to purchases?

Tags: steam-trading-cards

Are there any ways to recive cards without an payment had to be done(initial remaining card drops are bound to the game purchase itself)?

Or is it, that the total amount of existing cards is limited by the amount of money steam recived. And as those who consumed most cards (are related to the most money spent) have the highest probability to get a part of the cards that are removed from the system (selected for the random booster obtaining)?

Comment: False on point number two. Getting all the 'available drops' is enought to be eligible for a booster. Propably on point 3 too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @DJPirtu: Can you provide any source for this? and also: is this a criteria? ie having finished a badge but still having left remaining card drops, would I be able to recive boosters?

Comment: @DJPirtu: Point 3 can't be wrong.... its simply math.

Comment: @Zaibis having a finished badge and not having all cards from a game would not allow you to get boosterpacks for that specific game. What source do you have for this information? How do you know that is the only time booster packs are handed out?

Comment: Not addressing your individual points, but: Can you make a profit with no starting capital? Not easily. Can you start with a $20 investment and make upwards of $50 in profit through smart trading, buying, and reselling? I have.

Comment: "You are now eligible for a booster pack. Once you have received all of your card drops, you become eligible for a booster pack containing 3 additional cards. Booster packs are granted randomly to eligible users as more badges are crafted by members of the community. Make sure you log in to Steam each week to maintain eligibility." This from a set I've yet to complete. Refuters point 2. Point 3 is debateble based on one's interpetation. I have hard time beliving they wouldn't create extra packs as not all cards enter active circulation. It would keep the market going.

Comment: By the way, you are correct with your assumption that higher ranks give better propablity of a pack drop: http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq

Comment: The page you linked is even confirming my second point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't know what a ponzi scheme is.

Comment: @Studoku Explaining terms is one of the site's greatest strengths. If its misunderstood, that we can certainly help with. People not understanding terms isn't a close reason.

Comment: @Studoku: Thats right. I didn't know about that and I'm aggreeing.

Comment: @Frank: In that case I'm asking my self why this is so heavily downvoted if this should be in case a good question,then something is wrong with this community.

Comment: In your question title you ask if steam trading cards are a Ponzi scheme. In your question body you make the incorrect assumption that you need a full set of cards to get boosters -- you don't. You then ask a completely different question about getting cards for free. Your question has several problems and you need to decide what question is the one you want answered :)

Comment: I'm not saying it's a good question; I don't think it is.  But I don't agree with closing a question that revolves around a misunderstanding.  That said, @badp has it right; you're kind of all over the place.  Try to focus your question on what piece, specifically, you want to ask.

Comment: @badp: Well the point is, as it was pointed out: I had a wrong assumption of what a ponzi scheme is. So I was asuming my question and title is the same. So SLC's answer is giving me exactly that answer what solved my problem. But I can't understand why this is a reason for thath heavily downvoting me, while still making clear this is not off topic...

Comment: There are as many reasons for people to downvote the question as there are stars in the sky. But people tend to react best to questions that seem to be about solving a problem. The way your question is structured makes it seem more like a rant and a seek for approval. Especially on a skim-read.

Comment: @DJPirtu: I wouldn't call it a rant since thats what I'm knowing / was knowing about the system. SO AFAIK counting off putative facts, can't be a rant, and it wasn't my intention. I was looking for approval in the same as I was looking for disaproval by showing of why my assumption is wrong. Where the latter happened and I'm happy with it. and may there be as many stars as there want to be... I can't understand THAT negative voting on my post...

Comment: @Zaibis Now that you know how the system actually works and what a Ponzi scheme actually is I would encourage you to ask a new question if you want more information. The question has been downvoted due to the inflammatory tone ("this *has* to be a scam!"), falling flat for the XY problem ("I want to know that this is a scam, so instead I'll ask about these other things" that turned out to be irrelevant to your underlying claim), the poor research ("I brought no sources of my own, but can *you* bring proof that I'm wrong?"), ...

Comment: ...the incorrect assumptions that make the question almost unsalvageable and your lack of effort to address the criticism made in the comments, leaving the question as-is, *cosi è se vi pare.*

Comment: @badp: Ofcourse I could now edit the question with what improved my knowledge out of the comments. But I just felt everytime I noticed others doing this it was jsut confusing as it would change the question after an answer already was performed. Ofcourse I could aswell now start a new question. But for what reason since the question I was intending to ask is answered here. And neither was I claiming that something is as I state it, I was just expressing my knowledge about it. What in my view is the best way to express I'm looking for correction. I could edit that part out

Comment: if it is really making it so bad. But in my view that would just have not even shown any pre research, and thereby make the posts quality even worse. But ok, so here I go.

Comment: @badp: So and now this made up for what?

Comment: @badp: You see, that allone probably wasn't the point.

Answer (score 10):

No.

A ponzi scheme involves the first people to undertake it persuading more people to invest, their investment going upwards to the previous investors, and so on as more and more people join. There is nothing of substance or value behind the scheme so it will eventually collapse when enough people lose faith in it, by which point the initial investors will have profited.

Steam trading cards are a system where you can make purchases for prestigious awards (badges).  You do not automatically profit from people that invest money after you, as there is nothing to invest in. For it to be a ponzi scheme, each investor would have to receive a percentage of the money subsequent investors make, which does not happen.

The people that benefit financially are Valve, who charge a fee for trades within the closed system, and people that successfully trade for a profit (which is almost impossible).

The only method of making money is by the purchase and sale of digital items, therefore it is not a ponzi scheme, but a marketplace.